# Excel add one to the total

Tags: excel

I'm working on footy spreadsheets. I'd like to automate the win count. So column a is where the number of goals goes. Anything 3 or above is a win. If cell a1=3, a2=4, a3=2 a1 & a2 are wins, a3 is a loss. I keep the number of wins in cell b1. Every time the number in column a is 3 or more, I want to add 1 to the total in b1 but if it's a loss (less than 3) I want a running loss total in c1.
I hope that's clear and thanks for looking, BIG thanks for answering.

Cheers. :D

Comment: What have you tried before you posted question?

Comment: I type the totals manually, it works but it's time-consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula in cell `B1` = `=COUNTIF($A:$A, ">=3")`

Formula in cell `C1` = `=COUNTIF($A:$A, "<3")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use that expression:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A;">=3")
```